# Why does my router reject connections on port 80 from within my network?

Tags: router

The default gateway in my house is a Linksys router. When I open its web interface in my browser, I'm taken to the login page. I enter the credentials and the browser tells me that the connection has timed out. I check port 80 with portqry or nmap and I'm told that port is filtered. I try to refresh the web interface -- timed out again. I restart the router, check the port again, and it's open. I go to the web interface and the story repeats itself. What the hell?

Just to add a piece of information: it didn't use to do this. I don't know when this started because I don't go to the router's web interface on a regular basis.

Comment: Are you connected via Wi-Fi or with a cable? Some routers does not allow entering the management interface from wireless.  Have you tried with changing http:// to https:// ?

Comment: @Dempa I tried both wifi and cable. Only http:// works at all. the https port is closed at all times.

Comment: Have you tried from a different computer and web browser?

Comment: @Dempa, I don't have a different computer, but I have tried a different IP since I tried both the wifi and the cable connection on the same computer. Just installed Chrome to test it and it won't work. I've already tried Firefox and IE.

Comment: It could be that your router blocked your computers MAC address. But if you do not have any important configuration in the router I would recommend doing a reset of the router.

Comment: @Dempa The problem with this is that I tried both the cable and the wifi so different network adapters and different MAC addresses. I've also manually changed my MAC address to test this. Sure, I'll reset it to factory settings but is there a way to understand what the heck happened?

Comment: Currently I'm also a bit confused on why this has happened or how it could have happened without you changing any settings in the router. Try with the factory restore and hopefully that will solve the issue with that you can't access the management interface.